# Should I keep a feature branch regularly updated?

Tags: git, github, merge

So I have a main branch, into which we've been merging branches regularly. I regularly run `git pull` into my local main branch (pulling in changes others have made), and then merge those changes into my feature branch.

I'll then push up my feature branch changes, and merge that branch into main. Since main already has those changes someone else made, the only changes it doesn't have are the ones that I've made. So far, so good.

Now, I've made a separate remote feature branch, because I'm working on a very different feature that will need to be separated until it's complete. Let's call the local version of this branch `local feat` and the remote `remote feat`. After we've decided that `remote feat` is complete, we'll merge this into `main`.

But now, other people are merging changes into `main`.
How do / should I keep `remote feat` updated with these changes?

I could:

1. Not update `remote feat` at all, but that will cause merge conflicts when I try to merge it into `main` (because `main` will have changes `remote feat` doesn't have, and vice versa).
2. Regularly update `remote feat` with the changes I've pulled down from `main` into my local `main`. I'll then merge those changes into my `local feat`, and try to sync this with `remote feat`. The problem here is, when I sync it, it'll create a PR that must be approved. These changes have already been approved and merged, so I don't want to create a second PR for changes already merged into main.
3. Updated the smaller branch (lets call this `little local feat`) with the changes, and then merge these changes, with my own, into `remote feat`. The problem with this is that the PR (merging `little` into `remote feat`) will consider these already merged changes as new changes (since they're new to `remote feat`).

So of these three possible solutions, they all result in a pretty big issues. Which is the correct way to go about doing this?

Comment: (Way too many names.) First you say that you like to keep things up to date. I agree. Then you say that the “remote” feat (why is “remote” significant?) could get out of synch. if you don’t update it in the same way. Yes. So update it? I don’t understand why the same logic doesn’t apply to “remote feat”.

Comment: That PR requirement doesn’t make sense to me. Are you doing all of this “updating” locally or through some remote UI like GitHub/BitBucket UI (big green “sync.” button)? If so, try to do it locally instead.

Comment: From a development statement, you always want to keep your feature up to date as the main branch changes because this will reduce the chance of major merge conflicts happening as the trunk diverges from your feature branch. The most common mechanisms for doing so are (a) regularly rebasing your feature branch on top of the updated main branch or (b) regularly merging the main branch into your feature branch.

Comment: Is it the case that the "remote feat" branch represents a second (with `main` being the first) *shared* branch that multiple people are PR'ing their feature branches into? In other words that "remote feat" branch is more than just a bigger than usual feature branch- it's locked down and shared too?

Comment: Why would you in your solution 2 require a PR to merge to your own feature branch? That normally doesn't make sense.